# Robot Framework - Case sensitive

Tags: testing, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, functional-testing, robotframework

I need to know if there is a workaround on this error:

When I use Keywords like:

Location Should Be

Location Should Contain

(Which are both part of the [Selenium2Library](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html).)

I get this error:
"Location should have been 'http://www.google.pt' but was 'http://WwW.GooGLe.Pt'

I think that is because robot framework is natively case sensitive when comparing strings.

Any help?
Ty

**EDIT**
Question edited to clarify some subjects.

Comment: Why isn't the question clear enough? And was closed for not being a question. I don't get it.

Comment: Can anyone reopen this questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily Robot Framework allows for keywords to be written in python.

### MyLibrary.py

```
def Compare_Ignore_Case(s1, s2):  
    if s1.lower() != s2.lower():
        return False
    else:
        return True

def Convert_to_Lowercase(s1):
    return s1.lower()
```

### MySuite.txt

```
| *Setting* | *Value*        |
| Library   | ./MyLibrary.py |

| *Test Case* | *Action* | *Argument*
#
| T100 | [Documentation] | Compare two strings ignoring case.
|      | Compare Ignore Case | foo | FOO
#
| T101 | [Documentation] | Compare two strings where one is a variable.
                  # Should be Get Location in your case.
|      | ${temp}= | MyKeyword that Returns a String
|      | Compare Ignore Case | foo | ${temp}
```

I have not used the Selenium library, but the example in T101 should work for you.

Comment: where did you put MyLibrary.py file. are both files in same folder. i'm confused because you used  **./MyLibrary.py**  instead of **MyLibrary.py**

Comment: @GauravJain When you import `MyLibrary.py` in `MySuite.txt` the path in `| Library   | ./MyLibrary.py |` should be relative from `MySuite.txt` to `MyLibrary.py`.  In this case they should be in the same directory. However, if `MyLibrary.py` was under a directory called `rf_keywords`, and both `rf_keywords` and `MySuite.txt` where in the same directory then the import would look like `| Library   | ./rf_keywords/MyLibrary.py |`.

Comment: @GauravJain Also, `| Library   | ./MyLibrary.py |` is equivalent to `| Library   | MyLibrary.py |`.

Comment: so which one is better... I mean there should be some minor/major differences or issues ? which one you would prefer?

Comment: @GauravJain If I had multiple libraries I would put them all under a directory.  Otherwise, I would put the library in the same directory as the suite.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone else wants this:

```
Location should be '${expectedUrl}' disregard case
    ${currUrl}    get location
    ${currUrl}    evaluate    "${currUrl}".lower()
    ${expectedUrl}    evaluate    "${expectedUrl}".lower()
    should be equal    ${currUrl}    ${expectedurl}

Location should contain '${expected}' disregard case
    ${currUrl}    get location
    ${currUrl}    evaluate    "${currUrl}".lower()
    ${expected}    evaluate    "${expected}".lower()
    should contain    ${currUrl}    ${expected}
```